# Make class components available to a caller class but invisible to users in a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, access-modifiers

I have three classes in my project, whose ultimate goal is to create a single dll:

1. `public class Main`
2. `public class Helper1`
3. `public static class Helper2`

Those classes obviusly contain methods & variables that are either private or public. **How do I make the components of the helper classes invisible for an end user in a dll, but visible for the `Main` class?** I have a feeling this might be part of some broader programming concept that I am unaware of, so I'd be grateful for some links describing that in more detail as well.

```
public class Main
{
    public void MainMethod()
    {
        Helper1 h = new Helper1();
        h.DoSomething()
        Helper2.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class Helper1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

public static class Helper2
{
    public static void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

So, what I want to achieve, is to only allow the user who references my dll to be able to create an instance of the `Main` class and call the `MainMethod()`. I don`t want them to be able to create helper classes instances, neither do I want them to be able to call their methods.

Comment: Please pay attention to source formatting when you write a post - without the indentation, your code is *much* harder to read.

Comment: Yeah, was just editing it when a message came up than somebody else has just done that:)

Comment: Yes, I did it. But my point is that next time, please do it before you post the first version of the question. Read the question over before you post, and ask yourself whether it's in the state you'd want to see it if you were trying to answer.

Comment: Since this was my first post, I thought it would be automatically formatted when I use the "code" feature, especially that I don`t see the "indent" option in the edit bar. What I wanted to do finally was to manually add four spaces or a multiplication thereof to the code, but you were faster. Sorry I violated your sense of aesthetics, it was not my goal obviously. Is there any other way than adding manual spaces?

Comment: Well did you not start off with formatted code within an IDE? That's where I'd start. Aside from anything else, that way you can make sure you start off with valid source code (your original code *wasn't* valid - you had a `Helper1Method` method which was never closed). It's not a matter of my "sense of aesthetics" - it's a matter of one person (the person who'll benefit from the question being answered) putting in a bit of effort to help the many people who might be trying to help. The post preview is basically accurate - what you see there is what others see. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `internal` access modifier for them. For instance:

```
internal class Helper1
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //some code
    }
    ...
}
```